# tcpdump piped through grep written to file. (Weird number 16)

Tags: linux, redirect, pipe, tcpdump

I have the following command (I changed the ip to 8.8.8.8 for privacy reasons):

> tcpdump -i eth0 -nn udp portrange 27950-27970 and dst 8.8.8.8 | grep 'length 16$' > testfile

Pretty straight forward. I want all the incoming packets with the length of 16 written to a file, but for a very strange reason it doesn't work.

> tcpdump -i eth0 -nn udp portrange 27950-27970 and dst 8.8.8.8 | grep 'length 16$'

This command works fine and displays exactly what I want, just not in a file. So I am positive the packets are there. When I use the same command but with length 34 like this:

> tcpdump -i eth0 -nn udp portrange 27950-27970 and dst 8.8.8.8 | grep 'length 34$' > testfile

That does write it to the file, just not the packets I want. Why does the exact same command work with 34 and not with 16? What is so special about 16? I am completely confused because this seems impossible to me.

Originally I wanted to pipe the command again into sed. But piping also doesn't work with number 16. If I change "> testfile" to "| grep 8.8.8.8" then I won't get any output, and again with 34 I do get an output.

Can any of you make any sense of this all? Did I stumble upon a very strange bug? I have been trying and googling for hours but no luck.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: from man tcpdump: "-l Make stdout line buffered."

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried adding -l but without any luck. I get the same result. However it does have something to do with the buffer because I left the command on over night, and there was a result just now. The strange thing is that it only buffers if I add something after length 16$. "tcpdump -i eth0 -nnl udp portrange 27950-27970 and dst 8.8.8.8 | grep 'length 16$' | grep 8.8" doesn't give a result so it is buffered. But "tcpdump -i eth0 -nn -l udp portrange 27950-27970 and dst 8.8.8.8 | grep 8.8 |grep 'length 16$' does give a result while it is basically the same command.

Comment: @jww , it will be used in a bash script so it is very well a development question. Also in "What topics can I ask about here" it clearly states "software tools commonly used by programmers". I am pretty sure it also falls under that category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was: I did try making tcpdump line buffered -l but I didn't make grep --line-buffered. That does seem to do the trick.

That was my first problem, up to the next one. How to make sed line buffered.
And I can do that with the unbuffer command. So now I am a happy man.
Thanks @A.B for the help.

edit: This does actually work. So don't mind the downvote. It was probably one of them angry kids who shouldn't own a computer.